# Asciidoctor: Is it possible to activate section numbering in themes yml

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I know that I can use `:sectnums: all` after the title to enable section and subsection numbering. But is it possible to define this in the theme yml? I have a lot documents which use the same theme file, and it would be nice to have it defined only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF `theme.yml` does not support setting AsciiDoc attributes, so that approach won't work.

However, you can specify attributes on the command-line:

```
asciidoctor-pdf -a sectnums=all file.adoc
```

It might be better to create an AsciiDoc file that only defines attributes, say `attributes.adoc`. You would specify any attributes that you want to use globally:

```
:sectnums: all
:toc: left
```

Then, in every document that needs to use those attributes:

```
= My document
include::attributes.adoc[]

Lorem ipsum...
```

Once you've done that for all documents, adjusting the attributes requires editing only the `attributes.adoc` file.